# Receiving a large string in WCF service

Tags: c#, wcf, rest, serialization, http-post

Below is my service contract

```
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(Method = "POST", UriTemplate = "/SavePrint?seq={seq}", BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare)]
bool SavePrint(int seq, string print_lines);
```

The string will always be over 3000 characters so i cannot pass it in the Url.

Im trying to upload with the WebClient class.

```
WebClient client = new WebClient();
client.Headers["Content-type"] = "application/xml";
client.UploadString(baseURLTxtBox.Text + "/SavePrint?seq=1", LongStringHere);
```

When i try and pass it using the UploadString method of the WebClient class the service fails with the error `There was an error checking start element of object of type System.String. The data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1.`

I assumed because it is expected it as XML so i wrapped my string in XML

```
<string xmlns="">LongStringHere</string>
```

but then i get the error

> Unable to deserialize XML body with root name 'string' and root namespace '' (for operation 'SavePrint' and contract ('IPrintAPI', 
>   'http://tempuri.org/')) using DataContractSerializer. Ensure that the
>   type corresponding to the XML is added to the known types collection
>   of the service.

I dont know how i am supposed to add a string to the known types collection.

Answer (score 1):

Wrapping `"<string></string>"` is not the proper way to encode xml.
And not sure why you're encoding with xml....if the string isn't xml.

See

http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#form-content-type

Regardless....try

```
string url = baseURLTxtBox.Text;

using(WebClient client = new WebClient())
{
    System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection nvc = new System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection();
    nvc.Add("ParameterOne", "!@#$%^&*() Anything Any Characters Here");
    nvc.Add("ParameterTwo", LongString);
    byte[] responsebytes = client.UploadValues(url, "POST", nvc);
    string responsebody = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(responsebytes);
}
```

APPEND:

```
 [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", UriTemplate = "Mod?ParameterOne={ParameterOne}&ParameterTwo={ParameterTwo}")]
    bool SavePrint(string ParameterOne, string ParameterTwo);
```

APPEND:

Now try increasing your maxReceivedMessageSize.

```
<endpoint
          address  = "http://somethinghere"
    binding  = "basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpEndpointBinding"
    contract = "MyIService" >
</endpoint>

  <basicHttpBinding>
<binding name="BasicHttpEndpointBinding"
   maxBufferSize="9000000"
   maxReceivedMessageSize="9000000"                      >
  <security mode = "None">
  </security>
</binding>
```

Comment: What does my service contract need to be to accept this? Currently it doesnt match.

Comment: Made an edit.  I didn't wire it up perfecting, just showing you the idea/concept.  Get one or two strings working then tweak to match your exact signature.

Comment: Ok but that doesnt help. You are just adding the string into the URL. I cannot do this due to the size of the string being sent.

Comment: Does it work with a small string?  I added a "maxReceivedMessageSize" hint.  First get it working with a small string..then try to adjust the maxReceivedMessageSize setting.